# Is it possible to cast an Object using the contents of a String?

Tags: java, string, casting, runtime

**Retrospective note:** Most of this question doesn't make very much sense. It was my first question and is full of incorrect assumptions about how abstract classes worked. I won't be deleting it since some things may be learned from it, but I am aware that there isn't very much useful information that can be extracted from it.

---

### Things you need to know:

I have an abstract base class called Component...

```
public abstract class Component
{
    public abstract void doStuff();
}
```

I have some subclasses of Component...

```
public class Camera extends Component
{
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        //method specific to Camera objects
    }
}

public class Transform extends Component
{
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        //method specific to Transform objects
    }
}
```

### The Problem:

I need a method that can iterate through every single component in a HashMap and call the appropriate "doStuff();" method for each.

My first approach was to do something like this...

#### Example Driver Program #1:

```
public class Foo
{
    HashMap<String, Component> components;

    public Foo()
    {
        components = new HashMap<String, Component>();
        components.put("Camera", new Camera());
        components.put("Transform", new Transform());
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        //Assuming I don't know exactly what components are in the HashMap...
        //Iterate through all components,
        //Cast them to appropriate type,
        //Call "doStuff();" in all components.

        Iterator iterator = components.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Entry componentPair = (Entry) iterator.next();
            Component component = (Component) componentPair.getValue();
            component.doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code is wrong.
In the example above, every time I call *component.doStuff();* I will be calling the empty doStuff method in the Component base class. Therefore, **none of the subclass *doStuff();* methods are actually called**.

Remember, I **don't** want to cast anything to Component; I want to cast **only to subclasses** of Component.

For my second approach I tried to cast the components using the relevant String...

#### Example Driver Program #2:

```
...
while(iterator.hasNext());
{
    Entry componentPair = (Entry) iterator.next();
    String mapKey = componentPair.getKey().toString();
    Object mapValue = componentPair.getValue();
    Object component = Class.forName(mapKey).cast(mapValue);
    component.doStuff();
}
...
```

But this **wouldn't compile** because component was seen as type Object and *doStuff();* isn't a method in the Object class.

### Final Thoughts:

Is there a solution to this problem that doesn't require re-structuring the code?
It's possible that I have designed/structured this program really badly as I'm pretty sure that Dynamic casting isn't possible with Java.
If that's the case, can anybody tell me a good way to approach the problem? Maybe using interfaces instead?

Comment: Are you trying to just cast a String object to Foo? If so, create a constructor for Foo that takes a String

Comment: completely reminds me the first chapter of 'head first with design patterns' chapter1 - I think you should have a look

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your first approach, it will always call the doStuff of the specific instance, i.e Camera or Transform, not from the abstract class. Besides, doStuff() in Component is abstract, it can not be called.

Comment: Why are using a raw `Iterator` and raw `Entry`s?

Comment: Example Driver Program #1: should do what you want.  The abstract method is not called

Comment: “every time I call component.doStuff(); I will be calling the empty doStuff method in the Component base class.”  That is 100% incorrect.  Method resolution is based on the runtime type of the object.  A Camera instance retains its identity as a Camera instance forever, and its doStuff() implementation is always the method defined in the Camera class;  casting the instance does not change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is the way to go.

Let's assume you have the HashMap you described:

```
HashMap<String, Component> components = new HashMap<String, Component>();
components.put("Camera", new Camera());
components.put("Transform", new Transform());
```

If you need the keys, you can iterate over the EntrySet of the Map. If you just want to call the functions, you can use the map's values() function. This way you also don't need the iterator structure, but you can use a for each loop, which looks better in my opinion.

```
for(Component nextComponent : components.values()){
    // do some other stuff here
    nextComponent.doStuff();
}
```

The abstract method won't be called and you also don't need to cast anything right here, because the compiler already knows which function to call.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I remember, `HashMap` does not have an `iterator()` method.

This method would work perfectly, make the iterator on the `entrySet` instead.

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Component>> iterator = components.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    iterator.next().getValue().doStuff();
}
```

or if you only need the values

```
Iterator<Component> iterator = component.values().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    iterator.next().doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, `Component component` will be a instance of `Camera` or `Transform` or any other implementation of `Component` abstract class. Considering polymorphism (I suggest you to take a look at some articles about it, like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), overriden `doStuff()` method will be called. You don't need to cast `Component` instance to `Camera` or `Transform` explicitly, so your first example is the way to go.

```
   for (Component component : components.values()){
         // component may be a Camera or Transform. It doens't matter; override will be called.
        component.doStuff();
    }
```